# Any automatic way of obtaining the ELF section an address resides in?

Tags: binary, x86, elf

Suppose I've the address of some string or symbol in an ELF binary output by e.g. `strings -a` and want to know what section that address resides in.

Normally, I would do `objdump -h` and manually find the section address range that includes the address. However, this is both error-prone and extremely slow.

Are there easier methods for performing this task?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the address you’re looking for, as an offset in the binary, you could use something like this:

```
objdump -h /path/to/binary |
awk -v target=address 'BEGIN { target = strtonum("0x" target) }
                       NF > 1 {
                        if (typeof($1) == "strnum") {
                          if (strtonum("0x" $6) <= target) { section = $2 }
                        }
                       }
                       END { print section }'
```

replacing `address` with the hexadecimal address.

This can be adjusted to search for virtual addresses instead of binary offsets by changing the field (`$6`).